SignalR: Usage of multiple hubs in one function (passing hub as parameter)
My application consists of several web apps (portals). As an example we take 'customer portal' and 'manager portal'.
Each of these web apps works without dependencies on the other and therefore also has a separate SignalR hub setup and set up with DI. Each frontend also connects only to their hub.
Now I also have a project running shared jobs in hangfire.
An example of such a job is downloading a document. This is done Async and is the same for both web apps.
The request is called on the controller corresponding the webapp and it fires the shared hangfire job.
This job will make a signalR call to the webapp to let it know that it has finished downloading.
However, the shared job does not know which hub to call. Before this 'portal specific hub' change there was only one hub and it broadcasted it to all the users over all the portals.
How do I pass my hub to that hangfire job so it knows where to send the message to? Is this the right approach or is there a better way?
My setup is as follows:
Shared Hub interface:
public interface IMainHub
{
Task DocumentDownloadReady(int documentId)
}

Specific interfaces & hubs for web apps
public interface ICustomerHub : IMainHub
{
 Task SomeMoreFunctions()
}

public class CustomerHub : Hub<ICustomerHub>
{
    private readonly IExampleService _exampleService;

    public DesktopHub(IExampleService  exampleService)
    {
        _exampleService = exampleService;
    }

    public Task SomeMoreFunctions()
    {
        _exampleService.Example();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


public interface IManagerHub : IMainHub
{
 Task EvenMoreFunctions()
}

public class ManagerHub : Hub<IManagerHub>
{
    private readonly IExampleOfAnExampleService _exampleService;

    public DesktopHub(IExampleOfAnExampleService exampleService)
    {
        _exampleService = exampleService;
    }

    public Task EvenMoreFunctions()
    {
        _exampleService.Example();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


Download document Job Call (in..lets say Customer Web app):
public class DownloadDocumentRequestHandler : RequestHandler<Request, Response>
{
 private readonly IHubContext<CustomerHub, ICustomerHub> _hubContext;

 public DownloadDocumentRequestHandler(IHubContext<CustomerHub, ICustomerHub> hubContext) {
  _hubContext = hubContext;
 }

 protected override async Task<Response> Handle(Request request) {

// Old method:
_runner.Enqueue<IDownloadAttachmentJob, DownloadAttachmentParameters>(new DownloadAttachmentParameters(attachment.Id));

// What I tried:
_jobRunner.Enqueue<IDownloadAttachmentJob<CustomerHub, ICustomerHub>, DownloadAttachmentParameters<CustomerHub, ICustomerHub>>(new DownloadAttachmentParameters<CustomerHub, ICustomerHub>(attachment.Id, _hubContext));

}

Download Document Job:
public class DownloadAttachmentParameters<THub, THubInterface> where THub : Hub<THubInterface>
    where THubInterface : class
{
    public DownloadAttachmentParameters(int attachmentId, IHubContext<THub, THubInterface> hubContext)
    {
        AttachmentId = attachmentId;
        HubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public int AttachmentId { get; }
    public IHubContext<THub, THubInterface> HubContext { get; set; }
}

public interface IDownloadAttachmentJob<THub, THubInterface> : IJob<DownloadAttachmentParameters<THub, THubInterface>> where THub : Hub<THubInterface>
    where THubInterface : class
{
}

public class DownloadAttachmentJob<THub, THubInterface> where THub : Hub<THubInterface>
    where THubInterface : class, IDownloadAttachmentJob<THub, THubInterface>, IMainHub
{
private IHubContext<THub, THubInterface> _hubContext;

 public async Task Run(DownloadAttachmentParameters<THub, THubInterface> parameters) {
  _hubContext = parameters.HubContext;

  // download logic

  _hubContext.Clients.All.DocumentDownloadReady(parameters.AttachmentId)
 }


This does not work because the Hub<> does not allow an inherit from an interface. So
IManagerHub : IMainHub

Is not allowed. But even with placing the IMainHub method signature (DocumentDownloadReady(..)) inside the hub interfaces (duplicated) and replacing the generic call signature (IMainHub to IManagerHub, ICustomerHub).
public class DownloadAttachmentJob<THub, THubInterface> where THub : Hub<THubInterface>
    where THubInterface : class, IDownloadAttachmentJob<THub, THubInterface>, IManagerHub, ICustomerHub

I am still unable to pass it as a generic parameter.
Is this even the right approach?
Did I try considering groups? Yes, but within the manager portal, I already make use of groups in another situation (managers being in offices).
